# Gif doesn't want to move

Tags: html, css

my gif doesn't want to move, I've tried using left, right but nothing works, I need to put this picture in the middle of the two that are on top.

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1QJf.jpg)

```css
 /* Img*/
figure {
  position: relative;
  top: 1200px;
  right: -200px;
  }
    
  figure:before,
  figure:after {
  content: '';
  left: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  }
    
  img {
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }

  .image3 {
    border-radius: 20px;
    right: -500px;
  }
```

```html
<figure>
    <img src="webbsite skins pic.jpg" class="image1" style="width:500px;height:300px;">
    <img src="patterns.png" class="image2" style="width:500px;height:300px;">
    <img src="pattern_gif.gif" class="image3" style="width:700px;height:300px;">
</figure>
```

Comment: you can use `flexbox` to set the order of the images but you would probably need to lose the specific positioning that you have used on `.image3` - namely `right:-500px` and rely upon the `order` - but why have it placed at the end if you want it in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

With `Flexbox` you can change the `order` of elements quite easily within the flex-container. The container (`figure`) has had the absolute positioning removed so that you do not need to scroll way down to see the results

```css
figure {
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
  min-width:1700px;
  /*
  position: relative;
  top: 1200px;
  */
}

img {
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0.1rem;
  
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
}

.image1{order:1}
.image2{order:3}

.image3 {
  border-radius: 20px;
  order:2;
  width:700px;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" class="image1" />
  <img src="https://pngquant.org/Ducati_side_shadow.png" class="image2" />
  <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/6SZ5iwN70lJyOdLZZH/giphy.gif" class="image3" />
</figure>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try instead of positioning:

```
transform: translateX(your position)
```